# mysql Group by max id & left join another table

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE post_id IN (SELECT MAX(post_id) FROM posts GROUP BY album_id) 
AS T
LEFT JOIN album 
ON T.album_id=album.album_id
```

I have 2 tables, 1st I need get max post_id group by album_id

than I need to left join album ON album_id

```
post_id | album_id      album_id  |  album_title
1         0             0            abc
2         1             1            def
3         1
```

result should be

```
post_id   |  album_id   |  album_title
1            0             abc
3            1             def
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT * FROM
  posts p1
JOIN (SELECT album_id, MAX(post_id) post_id FROM posts GROUP BY album_id) p2
  ON p1.album_id = p2.album_id AND p1.post_id = p2.post_id
```